# The thin white line

Tags: bug, design

When clicking on the inbox, or the reputation, buttons on Skeptics, a thin white vertical line appears.

OSX machine 1, using Chrome

[image]

You can see one white line going through "Citing holoc**a**ust denial sites in answer regarded as **a**cceptable by moderators" but if you look closely, you can see three other thin white vertical lines.

I can't see it on Safari.

OSX machine 2, using Safari.

[image]

Nor can I see it currently on Chrome.

OSX machine 2, using Chrome.
[image]

Comment: FWIW: I can't see it on my machine (Windows, Chrome, several plug ins). What set up are you using? Do you use any browser plug ins that target Stack Exchange?

Comment: @Oddthinking I've updated the question.

Comment: I'm also seeing it on Chrome on Windows. Open the inbox or 'Help' menu for example, and four white lines appear - they're not easy to spot unless there's something like a large image. They appear when something in the top bar is opened and disappear when it's closed. Where they appear and how many appear varies by screen size